# Redirection to user page not happening

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, opayo

I am using simulator account with `server_asp.net-kit`. When I am running the application I reach the `Ready to Send the Notfication POST` page.

But from here I don't know how to redirect. I have tried:

```
RedirectURL=" & strYourSiteFQDN & strVirtualDir & "/PaymentConfimationPage.aspx?reasonCode=002" & vbCrLf
```

in `notificationPage.aspx` page.

Do I need to use this page? How to redirect? Code I have is in VB whether C# code available?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to some of the SagePay forums, the URL should be:

```
NotificationURL="https://" & strYourSiteFQDN & "/" & strVirtualDir.Trim() & "/PaymentConfimationPage.aspx?reasonCode=002"
```